# add custom field in com_category joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

i need to add a field into component com_categories, this is for i need add new values in categories, for example these are the archives that i modified:

Joomla 3.1.5

administrator\components\com_categories\views\category\tmp\

```
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">
                <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('subtitulo'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('subtitulo'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and too in this file:
administrator\components\com_categories\models\forms\category.xml

```
<field
    name="subtitulo"
    type="textarea"
    label="subtitulo"
    description="USE ESTE SUBTITULO"
    rows ="4" cols="6" filter="raw"
     />
```

So, the new field appear in backend administrator but when i save the new data incustom field... disapear!

The problem would be save the new field into Database or another method, because when i modify the template (default_items.php) can i se the changes i do, the new field if is saved must be appear using

```
<?php 
   print_r($this);
?>
```

but dont appear the new data (subtitulo), whats wrong??, how can i do to add new field in mod_categories and access it.

Comment: Does your component include categories and do you need only an extra field or do you need in general on all categories (content, weblinks, etc.) an extra field?

Comment: I need only in categories, default joomla have: title, alias, description, in categories. I need a new field (subtitulo) and obtain this value to show in layout categories

Comment: Where are you attempting to save this? You need to save it as part of the parameters field or else you need to add a new table to store it. In theory you could change the title field to fields and save it as json, but then you will have problems with alias creation. Another thing you could do is repurpose one of the images or url fields for this purpuse.

Comment: So, how can i do to save that new field, because i dont know how do it, save into table and obtain this value

Comment: A category is always attached to a component. So my question is in which component do you need to extend the category? IN the articles component? Otherwise I can't give you an advise.

Comment: is the component com_categories i need add a new value